# broken packages (update-notifier, update managticer) that disrupts all kind of installation using apt or apt-get or dpkg or even synap

Tags: update-manager, update-notifier

since a long time , I am having problems whenever I install a package. for example, when i try to install alien package that's what I get:

---

```
sudo apt-get install alien
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
alien is already the newest version (8.95).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [O/n] O
Setting up update-notifier-common (3.192.1.7) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloader", line 24, in  <module>
import debian.deb822
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/debian/deb822.py", line 38, in  <module>
import chardet
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chardet'
dpkg: error processing package update-notifier-common (--configure):
installed update-notifier-common package post-installation script     subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of update-notifier:
update-notifier depends on update-notifier-common (= 3.192.1.7); however:
Package update-notifier-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package update-notifier (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-desktop:
ubuntu-desktop depends on update-notifier; however:
Package update-notifier is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-desktop (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of update-manager:
update-manager depends on update-notifier; however:
Package update-notifier is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package update-manager (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because the error   message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
Errors were encountered while processing:
update-notifier-common
update-notifier
ubuntu-desktop
update-manager
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

---

j'ai essayé de fixer les paquets en supprimant mais le problème persiste

```
enter code here
sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up update-notifier-common (3.192.1.7) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloader", line 24, in <module>
import debian.deb822
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/debian/deb822.py", line 38, in <module>
import chardet
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chardet'
dpkg: error processing package update-notifier-common (--configure):
installed update-notifier-common package post-installation script     subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a   follow-up error from a previous failure.
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of update-notifier:
 update-notifier depends on update-notifier-common (= 3.192.1.7);   however:
 Package update-notifier-common is not configured yet.
 dpkg: error processing package update-notifier (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-desktop:
 ubuntu-desktop depends on update-notifier; however:
 Package update-notifier is not configured yet.

 dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-desktop (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of update-manager:
 update-manager depends on update-notifier; however:
 Package update-notifier is not configured yet.

 dpkg: error processing package update-manager (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
 No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a  follow-up error from a previous failure.
 No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
 Errors were encountered while processing:
 update-notifier-common
 update-notifier
 ubuntu-desktop
 update-manager
 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: duplicate? https://askubuntu.com/questions/986829/dpkg-error-on-terminal

Comment: Same kind of problem, but not quite identical.

Comment: Try `sudo apt install --reinstall python3-chardet` to get rid of the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chardet'` error, the very first in the cascade.

Comment: while trying to install by typing

Answer (score 11):

I encountered the same problem today. After a number of searches on the Stack Overflow site, no desired solution was found. However, I found a solution after searching on a Chinese website, and below are the solution:

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg
sudo mv info info.bak
sudo mkdir info
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Ref [here](https://blog.csdn.net/qingfengxiaosong/article/details/87889995)

Comment: worked for me like magic.

Comment: This works for me like magic though, I think there's still a vulnerability and just hiding the problems, feeling awkward ;(

Comment: It seems wise to restore the backed-up `info` folder after doing this.